# componentsSeparatedByString not working in swift

Tags: ios, string, swift

In My one app there is a time string in which i need to separate each part and process that.

My string is like

```
9:00 AM – 11:00 PM
```

or

```
9:00 AM – 11:00 PM,9:00 AM – 11:00 PM

Printing description of self.placeOpenTime:
"10:00 AM – 1:00 PM, 5:00 – 8:00 PM"
Printing description of allparts:
▿ 2 elements
  - [0] : "10:00 AM – 1:00 PM"
  - [1] : " 5:00 – 8:00 PM"
```

So my code to separate the string is

```
let allparts = self.placeOpenTime.componentsSeparatedByString(",")

for (index,_) in allparts.enumerate() {

     let currentPart = allparts[index]

     let timeParts = currentPart.componentsSeparatedByString(" - ")
}
```

from this code I am getting `timeParts` and `currentPart` as same like

currentPart = "9:00 AM – 11:00 PM"

and

```
Printing description of timeParts:
▿ 1 elements
  - [0] : "9:00 AM – 11:00 PM"
```

which should be

```
[0] : 9:00 AM
[1] : 11:00 PM
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Then the hyphen character in your code doesn't match the one in the text, check the Unicode values

Comment: @Wain Yes it is. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @wain commented, I have check for unicode value of "-" and it worked.

I have replaced this code

```
let currentPart : String = allparts[index]

let data = "\\U2013".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

let unicode = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding)

let timeParts = currentPart.componentsSeparatedByString(" \(unicode!) ")
```

Which is more complicated code to do small thing. So as per @Martin R suggest, the easy code to do this is

```
let currentPart : String = allparts[index]

let timeParts = currentPart.componentsSeparatedByString(" \u{2013} ")
```

Comment: That is far too complicated. You can write `componentsSeparatedByString("\u{2013} ")`, or just `componentsSeparatedByString("– ")` where `–` is the "EN-DASH" (option-minus on my keyboard).

Comment: @MartinR, Yes that worked. Thanks. I will update answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //may be issue with separetor string , once check is the separtor is proper string or not
 let timeParts = currentPart.componentsSeparatedByString("-")
```